# Make 3d-translated element clickable

Tags: jquery, events, css, click, translate3d

I have two divs inside a wrapper-div. 
The first one is positioned in front of the wrapper via translate3d(50px, 50px, 50px),
the second is positioned behind the wrapper via translate3d(50px, 50px, -50px).

I want to bind click-events to the inner-divs but i can't click the div which is positioned behind the wrapper.  Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

js-fiddle (webkit only): http://jsfiddle.net/rttmax/zrgdQ/16/

thanks. rttmax

Comment: your JSFiddle works for me on Chrome 20... when I click red or green rectangle, they both react on that click

Comment: wow, interestingly enough, when I reopened that same page, it stopped working :D

Comment: ja. sometimes it's working. most times not.

Comment: when I wrapped your live() bindings by $(document).ready() and updated that negative transformation to -43px from the original -50px, it always works - perhaps you can try to work out from that point on?

Comment: wow, so it doesn't work again when I forked that JS and tried to share it, it's back to not-working, sry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to give your wrapper DIV a positive 50px Z value in order to compensate for the negative 50px.

http://jsfiddle.net/zrgdQ/108/

Comment: This needs to be marked as the answer. Exactly what I was needing to fix my transform in Chrome and Safari.